# Get single row using Entity Framework without getting all data

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm trying to understand whether it possible to get a single row from a database using entity framework without returning all the data. Maybe I'm misunderstanding how EF work but I believe its similar to the following:

TBL1

```
Id | Name           | Place
 1 | Teressa Green  | UK
 2 | Robin Banks    | Germany
 3 | Liam Neeson    | Canada
```

If I want `Robin Banks` Id do something similar to

```
context.tbl1.where(obj => obj.name = "Robin Banks")
```

However from what I've understood this is getting all data from the table and then filtering down to the one row. Is there a way to return just the one row back to the logic without initially returning all the data?

To put the my issue in one sentence. I'm trying to avoid loading back all rows when I just want 1.

Comment: *"this is getting all data from the DB table and then filtering down to the one row"* no, it's not. Entity Framework will build a `SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE name = 'Robin Banks'` query and pass that to the database server, which will execute it as a normal query and return the appropriate rows to Entity Framework.

Comment: You are wrong. It will filter in database not in memory.

Comment: It will only filter in memory if you are doing something like this: `context.tbl1.ToList().where(obj=>obj.name="Robin Banks")`. Because you first load everything in the memory and then filter the data with the where() statement. But like it is done by you the filter is applied on the database.

Comment: Cheers guys this is what I wanted to hear, I couldnt find anywhere that told me this? Can you provide for me some links to which you found this info?

Comment: What you're looking for is [LINQ to Entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386964(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line will not actually execute anything on the database:

```
context.tbl1.Where(obj => obj.name == "Robin Banks")
```

It will return an `IEnumerable<tbl1>` which is going to be lazily evaluated when you come to use it. To execute an actual query on the database you need to perform an enumeration on the `IEnumerable<tbl1>` (e.g. a `foreach`, `.ToList()` or `.SingleOrDefault()`). At this point EF will convert your `Where()` clause into actual SQL and execute it on the database, returning the specified data. So, it will get **all data that matches your predicate** `obj.name="Robin Banks"`. It will not get all the data in `tbl1` using a SQL statement and then filter the results in .NET - that's not how it works.

However, you can do this (if you need to, but not recommended almost 100% of the time) by first enumerating with `.ToList()`:

```
context.tbl1.Where(obj => <some SQL evaluated expression>).ToList()
```

And **then** adding an additional predicate on the end:

```
context.tbl1.Where(obj => <some SQL evaluated expression>).ToList().Where(obj => <some .NET evaluated expression>).ToList()
```

You can log the actual SQL being generated by EF by doing the following with your context:

```
context.Database.Log = Console.WriteLine;
```

And see for yourself what's going on under the hood.

Comment: Thank you this was really helpful!

Comment: @downvoter - care to comment?

Comment: Additional information, this code `context.Database.Log = Console.WriteLine;` is for EF6 onwards only.

Answer (score 5):

I think you need to use here `SingleOrDefault`

```
var result= db.yourtable
           .SingleOrDefault(c=>c.Name== "Some Name");
```

Whenever you use SingleOrDefault, you clearly state that the query should result in at most a single result

Answer (score 1):

you are not sure if an item with a given key exists --> FirstOrDefault

[Entity Framework 4 Single() vs First() vs FirstOrDefault()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485317/entity-framework-4-single-vs-first-vs-firstordefault)