# Linq query not converting to string in MVC app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

This fairly simple `LINQ` query is being used to pull out a record based on its `ID` field:

```
string s = (from i in db.Categories
            where i.CategoryID == model.SelectedCategory
            select i.Name).ToString();
if (ModelState.IsValid && model.ImageUpload.ContentLength > 0)
{
    string InitialPath = string.Format("/Images/Products/" + s + "/"); 
    var PathWithFileName = Path.Combine(InitialPath, model.ImageUpload.FileName);
```

**Model:**

```
public class ItemVM
{
    public int? ID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name ="Category")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Please select a category")]
    public int? SelectedCategory { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Brand")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a brand")]
    public int? SelectedBrand { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Product name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the product name")]
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Price")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the price")]
    [Range(1, Int32.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Value should be greater than or equal to 1")]
    public decimal? ItemPrice { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Image Upload"), Required(ErrorMessage = "Product Image must be added.")]
    [NotMapped]
    [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
    public HttpPostedFileBase ImageUpload { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CategoryOptions { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> BrandOptions { get; set; }
}
```

I need to use `s` (string object) to name a folder. Unfortunately this query is not returning a string and I'm getting an error on the last line of code saying: 
`Illegal characters in path.`

Can someone please guide.

Thanks

Comment: Are you expecting a one item to return from the query?

Comment: Have you debugged and checked which value 's' contains? Maybe wrong data in the database?

Comment: @GiladGreen: Yes. Query is expected to return just 1 item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are getting the error is because `ToString` on the result of the linq does not return what you are expecting. It calls the `ToString` of the collection object - which returns the class's name.

Your linq returns a colleciton (even if it has a single item in it). What you want to do is to return that one item using `FirstOrDefault` (Or `SingleOrDefault`/`First`/`Single`):

```
string s = (from i in db.Categories
            where i.CategoryID == model.SelectedCategory
            select i.Name).FirstOrDefault();
```

And in that case you can better write:

```
string s = db.Categories.FirstOrDefault(i => i.CategoryID == model.SelectedCategory)?.Name;
```

- For more about the different methods: [Entity Framework 4 Single() vs First() vs FirstOrDefault()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3485317/6400526) (The part of EF isn't relevant here).
- For the Null Propagation read here: C# : [The New and Improved C# 6.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx)

Comment: What does that `?` in `string s = db.Categories.FirstOrDefault(i => i.CategoryID == model.SelectedCategory)?.Name;` mean?

Comment: @Dad It is the Null propagation operator introduced in C# 6.0. `FirstOrDefault` returns `null` in the case of an empty collection and then if you access the properties you will get an exception. This avoids that.