# Retrieve results from an EF linq query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am a bit new to C#. I am trying to retrieve a C# query and have some problems how to get my parameters i.e. id, location, name....

The result of query is in jobs and I want to retrieve jobs object to get all my data.

This is the code I have tried:

```
public .. searchRelevantJob(string skills, string location, string category)
{
    Database1Entities o = new Database1Entities();
    JobPost j = new JobPost();

    using (Database1Entities context = new Database1Entities())
    {
        // Query for all blogs with names starting with B
        var jobs = from b in context.JobPosts
                   where b.Locationn.Equals(location) && 
                         b.RequiredSkills.Equals(skills) && 
                         b.Department.Equals(category)
                   select b;               
        return jobs;
    }
}
```

Comment: this doesn't look like ado.net but EF? Can you specify what you're using exactly?

Comment: There is no need for the two first liens of the function. They are not being used anywhere

Comment: I am using entity Framework for database in visual studio using c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A linq query returns a collection of the type specified in the `select` clause. As such you want your method to return `IEnumerable<JobPost>`:

```
public IEnumerable<JobPost> searchRelevantJob(string skills, string location, string category) { ... }
```

(You could also see that if you debug and check what is the type of `jobs` - var is not a magic word, it is just there to help with long type names, don't let it confuse you)

In addition, I personally would go with method syntax here:

```
return context.JobPosts.Where(b => b.Locationn.Equals(location) && 
                     b.RequiredSkills.Equals(skills) && 
                     b.Department.Equals(category));
```

If you are expecting only one item then you can use `FirstOrDefault` instead of `Where`. See also: [Entity Framework 4 Single() vs First() vs FirstOrDefault()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3485317/6400526)

Comment: And how would i get/retreive the value of these variables(i.e. location)?

Comment: Also what would be the return type of function?

Comment: @ZAINAli - what do you mean? you have a collection of items so by iterating the collection you can access each specific item and its properties. As for the return type - I wrote it in my answer.

Comment: Above code gives error "The name b does not exist in the current context"